# New to selenium and python, can't figure out how to call an item from a list

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm new to using Python and working with Selenium automation testing.

I'm trying to grab a list of menu items which only reveal sub-items when hovered over.

I've gotten this far with using PyCharm debugger, and see the list being broken up into items. But when I try calling the one that matches the name of the item I want to hover over, it gives me an error about list indices cannot be str.

I've tried a few things to convert the list into strings by using "for" code but I'm not getting anywhere it seems.

```
   def test_confirm_claim_default_search(self):
        driver = self.driver
        claims_page = MemberDataPage(driver)
        nav_elements = claims_page.nav_elements
        form_elements = claims_page.form_elements
        html_elements = claims_page.html_elements
        claim_numbers = config['claims']['claim_numbers']
        claim_menu = config['claims']['menu']

        self.log_in()
        claims_page.wait_until_not_clickable(form_elements["page_loading"])
        menu_item = claims_page.get_element_text(nav_elements["menu_template_update"]).split('\n')
        for program in menu_item:
            self.append(program, 0)
        claims_page.hover_element(menu_item[claim_menu])
        claims_page.click_button(nav_elements["claim_service_link"])
        claims_page.wait_until_not_clickable(form_elements["page_loading"])
        results = claims_page.get_element_text(form_elements["claim_results"])
        claim_numbers = claim_numbers.split(',')
        for claim in claim_numbers:
            self.assertIn(claim, results)
```

Traceback:

```
"C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\QA-Automation\hx-automation\services\member_ds2\claims.py", line 21, in test_confirm_claim_default_search claims_page.hover_element(menu_item[claim_menu]) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the entire error message so we can see what line the error is on

Comment: Ah, of course

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\QA-Automation\hx-automation\services\member_ds2\claims.py", line 21, in test_confirm_claim_default_search
    claims_page.hover_element(menu_item[claim_menu])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode`

Comment: claim_menu needs to be a number

Comment: I've had that iteration in there once thinking it was the answer.

I get this error if I use menu_item[0]
`TypeError: find_element() takes at most 3 arguments (7 given)
`
Where the 7 is the full list of menu choices

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are trying to index a list at a nonsensical unicode value such as `'\u0394'`. So basically the computer has a list of some items (we'll say `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`) and you are asking it to find the `'\u0394'`'th numbered item in the list, which is very confusing for it. I'm not really sure what your goal is with this code, but I imagine a couple strategic `print()` statements can help you sort it out. I would start with replacing the line:

```
claims_page.hover_element(menu_item[claim_menu])
```

with

```
print(claim_menu)
claims_page.hover_element(menu_item[claim_menu]) # this is the same
```

This will give you an output to your terminal showing what `claim_menu` is right before you try to use it as an index, which should help explain why this is happening. To index into a list you need to supply an integer (starting at the 0-th item).